# Issues with GeoServer GetFeatureInfo request parameters

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I managed to make `GetFeatureInfo` request but it has some issues still.
This is code:

```
function request(e) {
  var BBOX = that.mymap.getBounds().toBBoxString();
  var WIDTH = 101;
  var HEIGHT = 101;
  // var X = that.mymap.latLngToContainerPoint(
  //   e.latlng,
  //   that.mymap.getZoom()
  // ).x;
  // var Y = that.mymap.latLngToContainerPoint(
  //   e.latlng,
  //   that.mymap.getZoom()
  // ).y;
  var X = 50;
  var Y = 50;
  let URL = `/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=cite:tbilisi3&STYLES=&LAYERS=cite:tbilisi3&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=${X}&Y=${Y}&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=${WIDTH}&HEIGHT=${HEIGHT}&BBOX=${BBOX}`;

  console.log(URL);
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    datatype: "html",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      // L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(data).openOn(that.mymap);
    },
  });
}
```

I have two problems:

- You can see the `bbox` contains all visible map, hence it makes request on larger region, how do I make this region smaller? e.g. when user clicks I only want info from a smaller region around the click, not whole visible map.
- This request works as it is now just there are many results due to `bbox`. But, if I uncomment X and Y and use them (instead of hardcoded values), the response doesn't arrive anymore and I think I also get error about invalid point. What is wrong with  my (commented) X and Y parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [WMS standard](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms) to find out how `GetFeatureInfo` requests are constructed.

`X` and `Y` are the pixel coordinates of where your user clicked on the map, these are added to the end of the `GetMap` request so that the WMS server can work out what is under the user's click. So the bounding box (and other parameters) must match the image your user is querying.

You could also consider using a pre-existing solution like [this](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms)

Comment: OP here didn't  finalize account registration. Thanks I will read it but it was exactly my question: What am I doing wrong with code with the way how I compute X and Y (the commented part)? Because I took that code from famous example on internet. Also how do I make a bbox for smaller area (where user clicked) instead of visible map area?

Comment: there is no need to make the area smaller, just stick with the map as displayed. I don't use leaflet but I expect the click event has a location in pixels

Comment: Oh, and thanks for telling us that you don't plan to stick around to be part of the community and "pay" back your help

Comment: Don't worry about sticking one of the goal for SE questions is that it is useful for future visitors too - so I at least payed back in that manner. Anyway, so you can't tell me what's wrong with the way X and Y are computed?

Comment: I just told you - don't use lat lon use the pixel values

Comment: Thanks but thats what `latLngToContainerPoint` should have done though IMHO ... (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html)

Comment: combining that with lying about the width height of the map will fail

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion I will check it a bit later